# Sumo's not finding the file.net.xml when I try to open the file.sumocfg

Tags: python, xml, sumo

I'm searching for a solution because I'm blocked and I don't understand why.
I'm a new user of Sumo, and to make my directory much clearer and less messy, I create a New Directory in the Directory where I put all files related to the sumocfg file I was working on (net.xml and rou.xml including sumocfg)
But now when I want to open the sumocfg file, it claims that the net.xml file is not found by searching it in the older directory it was.

Here is the error brought

[Errorfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffUiS.png)

And my problem is that he is searching the net.xml file in the path "Sumo/FirstIntersection.net.xml" instead of "Sumo/FirstIntersection/FirstIntersection.net.xml"

And I don't know why because when I open a simulation, I locate the good path.

[Opening Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN5pM.png)

I hope I was clear in describing the problem encountered.

Have some of you encountered the same issue?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sumocfg file is an XML file which you can modify with your favorite text editor. In your case it probably contains an absolute path to your network, that's why it does not work. You can simply change it to a relative path though. So instead of `<net-file value="/full/path/to/FirstIntersection.net.xml"/>` it should read `<net-file value="FirstIntersection.net.xml"/>`